# Enter the loop based on user parameter

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

There are 4 parameters .material,Suppliernbr,Suppliername,Materail code.My query is if the user enters any of the parameter with a single value in a single parameter i need to enter into the loop.

```
For Eg:
P_suppname='stack'
p_matrl='NULL'
p_suppnbr:=NULL
P_mtrlcde='NULL' I can go inside
```

But if

```
P_suppname=NULL
p_matrl=211
p_suppnbr:=43443443
P_mtrlcde='NULL' I shouldnt go.
```

ALSO

```
P_suppname=NULL
p_matrl='211;2322'
p_suppnbr:=NULL
P_mtrlcde='NULL' I should nt go
```

How to do this??

Comment: Your posted examples don't make sense: is 'NULL' the same as NULL?  In the first sample 'NULL' doesn't count as a value but in the third example it does.  Or do you mean that '211;2322' counts as two values?  It seems to me you need to re-think your interface.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of `;` in each parameter, using `nvl` to count zero on nulls:

```
select 
  nvl( length('211;2322')    - length(replace('211;2322', ';', ''))    +1, 0), -->2
  nvl( length('211;2322;34') - length(replace('211;2322;34', ';', '')) +1, 0), -->3
  nvl( length(Null)          - length(replace(Null, ';', ''))          +1, 0)  -->0
from dual
```

Using in an `IF`condition:

```
IF ( nvl( length(p_suppname) - length(replace(p_suppname, ';', '')) +1, 0)
   + nvl( length(p_matrl)    - length(replace(p_matrl, ';', ''))    +1, 0)
   + nvl( length(p_suppnbr)  - length(replace(p_suppnbr, ';', ''))  +1, 0)
   + nvl( length(p_mtrlcde)  - length(replace(p_mtrlcde, ';', ''))  +1, 0)
) = 1 THEN
  --LOOP
END IF;
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. The IF statement will sum to zero for each of the first two examples given in the question.

Comment: THIS WILL BE WRONG 

select 
  nvl( length('211')    - length(replace('211', ';', ''))    ,0), -->2
  nvl( length('211') - length(replace('211', ';', '')) ,0), -->3
  nvl( length('NULL')        - length(replace('null', ';', ''))        ,0), -->0
  nvl( length(Null)          - length(replace(Null, ',', ''))          ,0)  -->0
from dual

Comment: @Tobsey you are right, I fixed the answer. However, now it counts `'NULL'` as one parameter. This is not hard to solve, but I am afraid that doing it the solution would become too inelegant and difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great deal to be said in favour of the obvious solution.  After all, Nature has given us cut'n'paste, while not use it?

```
IF NOT ( (P_suppname is NOT NULL and p_matrl is null and p_suppnbr is NULL and P_mtrlcde is NULL )
    or  (P_suppname is NULL and p_matrl is NOT NULL and p_suppnbr is NULL and P_mtrlcde is NULL )
    or  (P_suppname is NULL and p_matrl is NULL and p_suppnbr is NOT NULL and P_mtrlcde is NULL )
     or  (P_suppname is NULL and p_matrl is NULL and p_suppnbr is NULL and P_mtrlcde is NOT NULL ) )
THEN
     raise_application_error(-20000, 'wrong number of parameters');
ELSE
    .....
```

This has the gigantic benefit of expressing its intent: it is clearly checking that one and only one parameter contains a value.  Other solutions may be whizzier but they will hinder people's ability to grok what they're trying to do.

---

Of course the posted code introduces some complexities.  The interface apparently allows the calling program to pass a string 'NULL' instead of just passing NULL.   Also, although it seems as though `p_matrl` is meant to be a number it is defined as a varchar2 so the calling program can pass nonsense like '211;2322'.

The proper way to address these flaws would be to fix the API so that it doesn't accept such nonsense.  That is the prerogative of the interface designer, to specify the contract which calling programs should adhere to.  In other words, if the calling programs pass 'NULL' instead of NULL reject their parameters.  Change the datatype of `p_matrl` to number.

But once APIs are in the wild and in use the burden of dealing with rubbish falls on the shoulders of the interface designer.  They have to include additional validational code.  This is the price of poor specification.  Unfortunately it is often not borne by the original person: the sins of the designer are visited on the maintainer.

Anyway, to address these issues we need to declare local variables and check/pass the parameter values.  Eg:

```
if p_matrl = 'NULL'
then
     l_matrl := null;
else
    l_matrl := to_number(p_matrl);
end if;
```

Do the validation for all the parameters, and use the appropriate variables in the IF statement above.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't imagine the type of interface that would produce such a requirement (or valid values of both `NULL` and `'NULL'`), but here's how I'd handle it:

```
DECLARE 

    cnt NUMBER;

BEGIN

SELECT DECODE(p_suppname, 'NULL',0, DECODE(INSTR(p_suppname,';'),NULL,0,0,1,0)) + 
DECODE(p_matrl, 'NULL', 0, DECODE(INSTR(p_suppname,';'),NULL,0,0,1,0)) + 
DECODE(p_suppnbr, NULL, 0, 1) + 
DECODE(p_mtrlcde, 'NULL', 0, DECODE(INSTR(p_suppname,';'),NULL,0,0,1,0)) into cnt 
from dual;

IF cnt = 1 THEN
    LOOP
        /* do whatever here */
    END LOOP;
END IF;

END;
```

I've assumed that p_suppnbr is a numeric, and all the others are strings.
I've also assumed that any parameter may be NULL, and that the string 'NULL' is equivalent to the NULL value.
(I've also implicitly assumed that any parameter with a semi-colon in it contains at least 2 values)